# Converting some java functions to php (char) and StringBuilder

Tags: java, php

i am trying to convert some functions from java to php, but i do not know java, can anybody help to convert these two lines from java to php ?

```
ac[i] = (char)(ac[i] - (i + 1));

md5(md5((new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(s1).toString())).toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function string_converter($s1){
    $ac = array('W', 'A', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4', 'Q', 'C');
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        $ac[$i] = $ac[$i] - ($i + 1); 
    }
    $s2 = implode("",$ac);
    return strtoupper(md5(md5($s2.$s1)));
}
```

Comment: thanks, for reply but i think i made a mistake somewhere can you look at the whole function please ? 

public static String _converter(String s1)
    {
        char ac[] = {
            'W', 'A', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4', 'Q', 'C'
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ac[i] = (char)(ac[i] - (i + 1));
        }
        String s2 = new String(ac);
        return md5(md5((new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(s1).toString())).toUpperCase();
    }

Comment: That's translated. Though your function is bad, you wouldn't substract numbers from chars... What is it supposed to do?